# Issues after EarlGrey installation

Tags: earlgrey

After EarlGrey installation, when running the program, it shows error as "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/EarlGrey.framework/EarlGrey".

But when running the test suite there is no issues encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the application? The application itself cannot be run with EarlGrey embedded inside it.

Comment: Yes while running the application, the error "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/EarlGrey.framework/EarlGrey." comes up, but while using in testing mode it works fine. Is anything wrong done installation?

Comment: The app will not run with EG already added into it. That's why we recommend a test rig instead.